# Mean value theorem for definite integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

In the MVT for definite integrals, I think the statement is that there exists **an internal point** $c \in (a,b)$ which has that property.

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = f(c) \cdot (b-a)$$

[MVT for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals)

Of course this is in the case when $a \ne b$ i.e. when we have a non-degenerate interval here.

Why? Well, if the function is constant, then any $c \in (a,b)$ does the job.
If the function is not constant, then (by carefully following the proof which uses Bolzano's theorem), one concludes that there exists **an internal point** $c$ with the desired property.

Could someone confirm my observations? I want to be sure because this MVT is used later when we write the residual term in Taylor's formula in [integral form](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Book%3A_Real_Analysis_(Boman_and_Rogers)/05%3A_Convergence_of_the_Taylor_Series-_A_%E2%80%9CTayl%E2%80%9D_of_Three_Remainders/5.01%3A_The_Integral_Form_of_the_Remainder) and more specifically even later in the form:

$$R_n = \frac{1}{n!} (x-\xi)^n f^{(n+1)}(\xi)(x-a)$$

($\xi$ plays the role of $c$ here)

So I want to know if we can **always claim** that this point is **internal** i.e.

- $\xi$ strictly between $a$ and $x$ (in Taylor's formula residual term)
- $c$ strictly between $a$ and $b$ in the above mentioned MVT

Comment: That is correct. You can also see it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals : *“.... achieves its mean value at some c in (a, b)”*

Comment: @MartinR Yes but above they say $c \in [a,b]$ And my textbook is also using some loose language in exactly the same place. That's why I decided to ask. So as long as the interval is non-degenerate then there's an internal point (always), right?

Comment: Nothing forbids the condition to also hold at $a$ or $b$, this does not really weaken the theorem. Consider $\sin x$ over $[0,2\pi]$. By the way, the Taylor remainder is always exactly $0$ at $a$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It may hold at $a$ or $b$ but I am claiming there's also an internal point at which it holds. Is that true? I followed the proofs carefully and it seems it is.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Otherwise, due to continuity, the function value would be lower or higher than the average over the whole interval, and this is a contradiction.

Comment: I don't know why textbooks state the weaker version, but what you say is correct. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem: *“... then there is a $c \in(a, b)$ such that $f(c) = u$.”*

Comment: @MartinR Not textbooks only, the wikipedia page also has $c \in [a,b]$ a few lines above the text which you quoted "achieves its mean value at some c in (a, b)" Thank you both for the confirmations.

Comment: @peter.petrov: Yes, I saw that. I don't know what else to say except “Yes, you are right.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

> $$m:=\dfrac1{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$ and assume that $$\forall c\in(a,b):f(c)\ne m.$$

Then by continuity of $f$ and WLOG

> $$\forall c\in(a,b):f(c)<m$$

so that

> $$m=\dfrac1{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(c)\,dc<\dfrac1{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}m\,dc=m\ $$

which is a contradiction.

The contradiction is lifted by

> $$\exists c\in(a,b):f(c)=m.$$

Comment: @peter.petrov: why ?

Comment: Why I edited? I only removed the exclamation mark as it looked to me like a factorial. A red factorial, what's more.

Comment: @peter.petrov: I precisely painted it red and inserted space to avoid any stupid confusion.

Comment: OK, well... if you like it that much we can put it back, sorry.